# How do I know when an Android app is launched and destroyed?

Tags: android, exit, launch

I need to run some code when an App is launched and when it completely exits (is destroyed). I am using onCreate and onDestroy but unfortunately screen orientation changes destroys and recreates the activity.

Comment: Specify in your manifest that you handle config changes (the list of potential ones gets longer with each API release).  Beware though that there is no guarantee the process will survive long enough for onDestroy() to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Android Application http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

You can know when Application created (Application.onCreated)

BUT you can't know when Application destroyed. Application.onTerminate() is only for use in emulated process environments.

Comment: This seems to be a good approach. I need to pass in a variable into the constructor. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Answered my own question: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Every time the app launched the `onCreate` method of your **launcher activity** is called. So you have to put the desired code in `onCreate` method of the Launcher activity.

And to detect whether your app is destroyed or not you can `override` `onDestroy` method ( just like adding the `onCreate` ) from **Override unimplemented method** menu. And put the codes inside of this method that you want to be executed when the app will be destroyed.

Comment: This does not work because when the screen orientation changes, the activity is destroyed and recreated. I don't to run my code in onCreate and onDestroy in these instances.

Comment: Would you like to fix the screen orientation or it is a requirement to keep orientation functionality enabled in your app?

Comment: Required to keep orientation functionality in the app

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, if your code can happen in the background (won't work if you need something to happen on the UI Thread):

Have your activity hold a reference to a thread you extended, let's call it MyThread operator.

In onCreate, do that:

```
if(operator==null){
    operator = new MyThread();
    operator.start();     
}
```

Then, in MyThread, put your code in the two methods `run()` and `interrupt()`.

When your activity gets recreated through orientation change, it will keep the operator refence to your background thread. When you actually close your application, android will terminate your operator after some seconds and therefore execute your code.

Someone correct me please if I'm wrong, I haven't slept too long lately and threads always are a complicated topic...